# How can I extend the header to the full page width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I extend my header to the full page? I have tried margin-left & right but that doesn't work.

Header.css

```
.header{
    background: green;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
} 


  .header-right {
    float: right;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }
```

Here's my app.tsx file:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header'>
  <h1>Instaride</h1>
  <div className="header-right">
    <Button> Sign In</Button>
    <Button> Contact</Button>
  </div>
</div>
);

export default Header;
```

I have already tried this too:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with this code, what result?

Comment: It works perfectly alright for me with whatever code that you have shared - https://react-xukh1h.stackblitz.io

May be you have included some css themes or library which might be intruding whatever that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It works perfectly alright for me too...

Comment: don't repeat the question. Edit the old one if you think the duplicate isn't suitable. Your old question is still visible in the first searching page

Comment: @TemaniAfif I posted again after my first one was unnecessarily closed. The suggested link did not help in my case :)

Comment: this is not how the site works. You don't repost the same question if you feel it's *unnecessarily closed*. You edit the question and you vote to reopen it.If it's wrongly closed it will get reopened. Spamming the site with the same question will simply get you banned.

Comment: Just inspect the code in the browser and see which css class/definition is adding the margin. If it is some class from Bootstrap or any other library, then you have to change the precedence of the library import to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `document.body.style.margin = 0;` in your component.

Here is your component with MUI way of styling,

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  header: {
    background: "green",
    height: "70px",
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginBottom: "25px",
    left: "0",
    right: "0"
  },
  headerRight: {
    float: "right",
    color: "blue"
  }
});

export default function Header() {
  document.body.style.margin = 0;

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.header}>
      <h1>Instaride</h1>
      <div className={classes.headerRight}>
        <Button> Sign In</Button>
        <Button> Contact</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also created sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sun-n5rth?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: But the css is same, no? It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: My bad, just add `document.body.style.margin = 0;` in your component and it should work all fine. Also edited the post and working sandbox.

Comment: If I use this in const Header() as it, it gives me an error. Is there anyway I Can integrate it in my existing code? If I put it on top of my style sheet, it gives an Unknown word error.

Comment: Even by removing the `document.body.style.margin = 0;` in the codesandbox, the header is being displayed perfectly alright. So this cannot be a solution. There has to be some CSS precedence. Unless we get the codesandbox from the questioner, it's difficult to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

It works perfectly alright for me with whatever code that you have shared - https://react-xukh1h.stackblitz.io

May be you have included some css themes or library which might be intruding whatever that you are trying to achieve.